# Which browser matches user-agent "mozilla/3"?

Tags: user-agent

I'm seeing some really old and ugly code in a project. It tries to sniff the user agent and do stuff accordingly

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('mozilla/3')) { ... }
else { ... }
```

I'm gona go ahead and remove this block of code if it's an ancient browser.

Comment: Seems to be Netscape3 according to http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Netscape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an very suspicious User Agent, because Modern User Agents more look like this:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36

The User Agent `Mozilla/3.0` belongs to the Netscape 3.0 Browser, which was current *circa* Windows 95. The last release of Netscape was version 9.

So, this code is totally outdated. Feel free to remove it!